# Extracting adjective phrase from a sentence

Tags: computational-linguistics

Could someone point me to some open source NLP or machine learning library that can be used (possibly with some additional processing) to extract an adjective phrase from a sentence? I.e, given the following sentence:
"There was a very nice weather during our holiday"
I'd like to extract "very nice weather".

Thank you!

Comment: "very nice weather" is not an 'adjective phrase', it's a noun phrase containing an adjective. Extracting such phrases based on syntactic category would take many steps, e.g., the corpus would require POS-tagging. Therefore, the question is not specific enough to find an answer to, and it shows that you did not do prior research.

Comment: @aslakr Thanks for the comment. What about "the weather is very nice"? Regarding your other remark, what could be "not specific enough" about a question that merely asks to point me to the right direction?

Comment: @OP What you're asking for is more or less an introductory course to computational linguistics, that's why :) <3

Comment: @aslakr are you suggesting I take the course before I start asking? :) I've seen plenty of very basic questions asked on StackOverflow, but never seen anyone downvoted for that.

Comment: @OP Actually, you're right, but the question is almost unanswerable anyways. Btw, *the weather is very nice* is a sentence, so depending on the annotation it's most likely either S or CP.

Answer (score -1):

Three such python package suites worth to mention:

PythonXY http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/
Enthought Enthought Python Distribution
Anaconda from Continuum: Python Visualization and Data Exploration

Comment: This is by far too unspecific. These are complete Python distributions/tool collections/platforms to be used for a large variety of scientific purposes and don't really help with how to approach the question's particular issue. You'd need to specify which exact packages provide methods for what Sasha wants to achieve.